# Eslint not working with the TypeScript syntax

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am trying to configure `eslint` for my `REACT-TypeScript` project. It was previously using `tslint` which is going to deprecate soon. I have gone through the web and finally was able to create my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest/globals": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "jest", "prettier"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["src/serviceWorker.ts", "src/enums.ts", "node_modules/"],

  "rules": { },
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "prettier/prettier": [
    "error",
    {
      "singleQuote": true,
      "semi": "error"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the `lint` command, it throws errors about the `TypeScript` syntax. Here are few:

[image]

[image]

All links on google are now purple and still, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Please help me to see this through.

Comment: Could you share your package.json (at least the dependencies and devDependencies arrays)?

Comment: That's a parsing error. Are you sure you are not putting TypeScript into JavaScript files?

Comment: What about that `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

To me your configuration seems good. If it is a Typescript error there is nothing you can do with ESLint. Just upgrade Typescript.

Just in case check this **ESLint Prettier Typescript** configuration which is a reference to me https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setting-up-eslint-with-prettier-typescript-and-visual-studio-code-d113bbec9857? it is close to yours

Comment: It's not a Typescript error; the Typescript code is correct. The problem is that ESLint doesn't recognise the Typescript syntax.

Comment: However I am seeing plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended

Comment: Eslint is not recognizing the syntax of TypeScript despite all the configurations

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to specify `parser`, `parserOptions`, `settings` for TS or react. You can just extend airbnb TS config, and add the other plugins like (jest, prettier, ...) only:

So your `.eslintrc` will look like:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-typescript", "plugin:jest/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["jest", "prettier"]
}
```

to install airbnb TS config

```
npm install eslint-config-airbnb-typescript \
            eslint-plugin-import@^2.18.2 \
            eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.2.3 \
            eslint-plugin-react@^7.15.1 \
            eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.7.0 \
            @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^2.7.0 \
            --save-dev
```

[or refer to the package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript)

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer the question